# passing argument between grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

I run a grunt task which calculates some stuff and puts the result in a variable. Later I want to use this result in another grunt task. I tried a lot of things to share this result between this two tasks but I did not succeed.

Have you got any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

finally I found a good solution,

I use grunt.config

In the task which is calculate the result I had

```
grunt.config.set('result', result)
```

And I can access it in other task with

```
grunt.config('result')
```